# Using multiple Mixins as inherited, order of methods execution problem

Tags: django, django-views

I have the following structure in Django:

```
class EmailView(View, ABC):

    def post(self, request):
           pass

        def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
         context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
           .........


class Base(AccessMixin,  EmailView, ABC):
      .....


class ADTView(ABC):
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        .......

class BaseMixin(Base, SubscribeNewsletterView, ADTView, ABC):
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
           ..............


class ItemListView(BaseMixin, ListView):
     ...............
```

If `EmailView` is inherited by `Base`(as in example) the method `get_context_data` from `ADTView` is not called.

If `EmailView` is not inherited by `Base` :  `class Base(AccessMixin, ABC)`

the method `get_context_data` from `ADTView` is called.

What is in the method it, doesn't matter (even if I get context , not modifying and returning it) the same thing happen.

What I want is the execution of the method order:

```
AccessMixin, EmailView, ADTView, ListView
```

I suppose is happen because `ListView` inherits from `View`, but in `EmailView` I used `View`, because I need `as_view`. Basically I'm calling the `EmailView` with an url, using Ajax.

Comment: Try using *only one* `View` for each of your CBVs; all other functionality should be provided by single-purpose mixins. Following MRO is *not* easy; for some examples of MRO for CBVs and CBVs in general I also recommend taking a look at my comprehensive CBV guide:  https://spapas.github.io/2018/03/19/comprehensive-django-cbv-guide/

Comment: I have 2 Views, because I have forms that are site-wide. So I need the context to be available on each page load, also This forms are sent using Ajax so I need them to have also post. and submission from url.

Comment: Have you looked into context processors? They're meant to be used for repeating context (ex. forms). If the forms are submitted with Ajax you just need a single view for each form and you don't have to worry about adding the context to your regular views.

Comment: @bdoubleu I used context_processors, but only for variables, I din't know that something complex as a form can be passed.My Views can have also forms. Think like a generic searchbox, available also on create Item.

Answer (score 1):

In fact Python MRO use depth first approach,and you can check the MRO by this code

```
print(ItemListView.__mro__)
```

Comment: thanks,  I know is a MRO problem, what I'm interested how to fix it in Django, and maintain the functionality